# Is there a way to block my JS code until the XMLHttpRequest response arrives?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, nonblocking

I'm trying to import some data through a PHP file with this function:

```
sendJsonRequest("initial", startID);
json = JSON.parse(request);

function sendJsonRequest(type, id) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            request = xmlhttp.responseText; //writing the response in an already defined variable
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","../RequestHandler.php?"+type+"_"+id,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The import of the data works very well. My problem now is that I want to use my request right after calling this function, to which point it's still not available (I realized this happens because onreadystatechange runs as function independently), therefore I have to put in some delay until it is so. I find the use of setTimeout or setInterval very uncomfortable, since those aren't blocking the code and I had to refactor some of my code very badly and inefficient. That's why I was looking for a way to modify/block out the function at its end, until the request is available, but neither using an empty while-loop nor the wait/pause/sleep-functions are recommended. Can anybody figure out another way to accomplish this?

Comment: You don't want to block your code until an async thing completes. Much better to NOT block, but rather let the rest of your code execute ASAP. Whatever you want to have happen *after* the async result should be based either on your function taking a callback to execute later, or returning a promise that can be `.then`'d. From a timing perspective it's the same idea.

Comment: Well, you *can* make it blocking by using setting the `asynchronous` flag to `false`, but that's as much recommended as the infinite sleep loops.

Comment: @Bergi: I tried as you said to set the asynchronous flag as false, and it actually works flawless with my code. Well, the requests are running on my localhost at the moment which has barely any delay, I wonder if this will work on a real server though...

Comment: @StrikeAgainst: As we all said, you really shouldn't do this :-) But we can't hinder you.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just pass a callback?

```
function sendJsonRequest(type, id, callback) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            request = xmlhttp.responseText; //writing the response in an already defined variable

            if(callback) {
                callback(request);
            }  
        }
    }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","../RequestHandler.php?"+type+"_"+id,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and use it like:

```
sendJsonRequest("initial", startId, function(req) {
    var json = JSON.parse(req);
});
```

Comment: Hmm that still would need me to refactor my code, wouldn't it?

Comment: Well,  the callback will execute immediately after the Ajax request is complete.  This is the first time the response is available.  So all the code you want to run that needs the Ajax response should be in the callback.   So basically you are just wrapping your following code in the callback.  Without seeing all the code,  it's hard to tell how much refactoring will need to take place

Comment: And that's my problem, the upcoming code is too big to be manageably re-factored... I have set the asynchronous flag to false now, though many people seem to not recommend it, it works flawless with my code.
EDIT: Still, the callback functions seems like a more appropiate to wait for the response than e.g. setInterval. I may need this in the future, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `Promise`

```
var sendJsonRequest = function sendJsonRequest(type, id) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            request = xmlhttp.responseText; 
            resolve(request);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.error = reject;
    xmlhttp.open("GET","../RequestHandler.php?"+type+"_"+id,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

sendJsonRequest("initial", startID)
.then(function(data) {
  // do stuff
  var json = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(json);
}, function err(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```